# How splits are calculated in Decision tree regression in python

Tags: scikit-learn, cart

I'm using scikit-learn to build a decision tree (or a random forrest) for a regression problem. I have continuous variables as my regressors. I wonder to know how the splits in a [regression decision tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_tree_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-tree-regression-py) in scikit-learn are being calculated? That is, how it searches through the space of all possible split points to determine which one is the best split point for a continuous variable?  The implementation is based on CART.

I've seen some using the

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring all optimizations, what you should do to find the best split for a given continuous feature is to sort your samples (say we have $n$ of them) and try all $n-1$ split points to see if which one is the best. For example, when your samples ar sorted, e.g. sorted version is $x_1,x_2,...x_n$, you need to try thresholds between pairs $(x_1,x_2)$, $(x_2,x_3)$, ...$(x_{n-1},x_n)$, in which you have $n-1$ of them. When this is done for all candidate features, you find the best split. Of course, there will be several optimizations such as *presorting*, using the information available from *ascendants* etc, which scikit-learn uses in its [Splitter](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx) implementation.